# Network packet editor for Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, packet, sniffing

Anyone know network packet editor for Linux, or a way to modify network packets in wireshark?

Answer (score 0):

HPing: http://www.hping.org/

> hping is a command-line oriented TCP/IP packet assembler/analyzer. The interface is inspired to the ping(8) unix command, but hping isn't only able to send ICMP echo requests. It supports TCP, UDP, ICMP and RAW-IP protocols, has a traceroute mode, the ability to send files between a covered channel, and many other features.
>
> While hping was mainly used as a security tool in the past, it can be used in many ways by people that don't care about security to test networks and hosts. A subset of the stuff you can do using hping:
>
> - Firewall testing
> - Advanced port scanning
> - Network testing, using different protocols, TOS, fragmentation
> - Manual path MTU discovery
> - Advanced traceroute, under all the supported protocols
> - Remote OS fingerprinting
> - Remote uptime guessing
> - TCP/IP stacks auditing
> - hping can also be useful to students that are learning TCP/IP.
>
> Hping works on the following unix-like systems:
>
> > Linux, FreeBSD, NetBSD, OpenBSD, Solaris, MacOs X, Windows.